# Тире или двоеточие перед приложением?

Tags: пунктуация, приложение, вставная-конструкция, тире-или-двоеточие

**Его** (?) **назовём это так** (?) **жизнелюбие привело к трагическим последствиям** (?) **алкоголизму и ранней смерти.**
Вставная конструкция "назовём это так" выделяется с двух сторон запятыми или скобками?
Перед приложением "алкоголизму и ранней смерти" нужно поставить двоеточие или тире?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[§ 97. Вставные конструкции (слова, сочетания слов, предложения) выделяются **скобками** или **тире**...](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=128#pp128)

> Перед приложением "алкоголизму и ранней смерти" нужно поставить
>   двоеточие или тире?

Лучше, по-моему, тире.

[**§ 36…** Примечание. Допустимо используемое в современной практике печати при всех позициях обобщающих слов употребление тире, в том числе — перед перечислением (на месте традиционного двоеточия): *В новом цехе организуется массовое производство изделий для машиностроения — втулок, стаканов, зубчатых сеток…*](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113#pp113)

Comment: Спасибо, slava1947!

Answer (score 2):

В этом предложении нужно поставить двоеточие, потому что слова "трагическим последствиям" - это скорее не обобщающее слово при однородных членах, а определяемое слово при последующих приложениях, которые имеют пояснительный характер и стоят в конце предложения

Comment: Его  (назовём это так)  жизнелюбие привело к трагическим последствиям: алкоголизму и ранней смерти.

Comment: Так правильно ?

Comment: Привело к трагическим последствиям (а именно каким?) - алкоголизму и ранней смерти

Answer (score 1):

А мне кажется, что вставка *назовём это так* находится не на месте (по смыслу предложения): поясняете Вы не слово ***его***, а слово ***жизнелюбие***.
Предложение, думаю, должно иметь такой вид:

**Его жизнелюбие (назовём это так) привело к трагическим последствиям — алкоголизму и ранней смерти.**
[Скобки и тире.]

Или такой:
**Его жизнелюбие — назовём это так — привело к трагическим последствиям: алкоголизму и ранней смерти.**
[Парное тире и двоеточие.]

[**Вариативные знаки препинания. Двоеточие — тире**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=189)